# Allowing access to my server's UDP ports when the server is connected to OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, openvpn

I've recently bought some cheap vps, and would like to open some ports, I already done that on server with ufw. btw I'm connecting to a VPN that allows me to forward ports to my local machine via OpenVPN since my local provder is blocking ports.

OpenVPN works fine on my pc all connected and working but it shows me only TCP ports are open,all UDP ports closed when i connected on VPN, but when I check on some webiste port checker and paste IP of server it tells its open..

I guess it has somehing with iptables or something like that..? Could anyone help me? THANKS

**EDIT. I made this work by doing these commands:**

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d SERVERIP -p UDP --dport 1234-j DNAT --to-dest 10.8.0.6:1234

iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp -d 10.8.0.6 --dport 3480 -j ACCEPT
```

and 10.8.0.6 is IP of OPENVPN

Comment: Sorry, this is a bit confused, how did you check that UDP port is closed (this is technically not possible like you can do with TCP port with telnet by example). In fact, what do you want to open?

Comment: First of all thanks for answering. i want to host games in ps4 so my plan was to order server setup vpn and have open ports simple as that.. but when i setup everything i saw on ps4 that nat is still not open.. Then i check on my pc with this tool and saw this:
TCP: https://img.techpowerup.org/190403/capture094-20190404.jpg
and UDP: https://img.techpowerup.org/190403/capture095-20190404.jpg

Comment: I think, instead of **EDIT. I made this...**, you should answer your question using what you've answered in **EDIT** and accept it after two days will expire.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are trying to achieve, you are try to do NAT from a VPS and forward TCP and UDP port to a local network reachable through a VPN tunnel (OpenVPN). This is probably not working due a routeback issue, your local network is probably configured to reach internet without using OpenVPN connection, so traffic coming from your NAT will not answering to your VPS.

What you can try is proxying your traffic over a service (like nginx). Here an example.

Install Nginx (on your VPS):

```
apt install nginx
```

Create a new folder dedicated for your port rules

```
mkdir /etc/nginx/ports/
```

Add the following lines to the end of the file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
stream {
  include /etc/nginx/ports/*;
}
```

Finally create any file you want with your rules, into this new folder. Here an example of tcp and udp redirect.

```
server {
  listen 1234;
  proxy_pass <computer-ip>:1234;
}

server {
  listen 1234 udp;
  proxy_pass <computer-ip>:1234;
}

Of course, port 1234 must be opened in your ufw as your mentioned.
```

Comment: Im gonna try this right now and i will update results

Comment: I still didnt get it working, have i done something wrong??
UFW: https://img.techpowerup.org/190403/capture096-20190404.jpg

https://img.techpowerup.org/190403/capture097-20190404.jpg

Comment: ProxyPass should be the local IP, not the public one.